# Async ajax calls and Controller/ajax interaction

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following scenario. I have a site and I want to copy files after a click on a button (#btn) and the site should show the progress bars when the files are copying. So i have a Controller called Retrieval with the void function Copy that does this job. My approach was the following: I iterate through the names in the Model and create an ajax call that runs the function. At the same time I update the progress bar. Now when I run the program the copying of the files is correct, but the site just shows the progress bar for the last file updating itself. The other progress bars remain untouched.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".property-progress").progressbar({ value: 0 });


$("#btn").click(function () {



    @foreach (var job in Model)
    {
    <text>


    var tmp = "#" + '@job';
    var intervalID = setInterval(updateProgress, 250);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Copy", "Retrieval")',
        data: { job: '@job' },
        async: true,
        success: function () {

            $(tmp.toLowerCase()).progressbar("value", 100);
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        }

    });

    function updateProgress() {

        var value = $(tmp.toLowerCase()).progressbar("option", "value");

        if (value < 100) {
            $(tmp.toLowerCase()).progressbar("value", value + 1);
        }
    }


    </text>
    }

    return false;

});
</script>
```

Regards craft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems are that you are generating the same variable `var tmp` and the same function name, `updateProgress`, over and over in the same scope. To JavaScript they are all the same variables. View the created source code of the page and see the large amount of similar code you are creating.

One solution, which I dislike, is to create each variable/function with unique name e.g. `tmp@(job)` and `updateProgress@(job)`. This is horrible because you are really performing one operation on multiple target items and should not duplicate code.

A better idea is to inject the list of items into a JavaScript array and write normal client-side jQuery to process that list of jobs:

```
var jobs = [ '@string.Join("','", Model)'];
```

then process with plain jQuery using scoped functions to retain the job id. Something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i< jobs.length; jobs++){
    processJob(jobs[i]);
}

function updateProgress(tmp) {
    var value = $(tmp.toLowerCase()).progressbar("option", "value");

    if (value < 100) {
        $(tmp.toLowerCase()).progressbar("value", value + 1);
    }
}

function processJob(job){

    var tmp = "#" + job;
    var intervalID = setInterval(function(){updateProgress(tmp)}, 250);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Copy", "Retrieval")',
        data: { job: job },
        async: true,
        success: function () {
           $(tmp.toLowerCase()).progressbar("value", 100);
           clearInterval(intervalID);
        }
    });
}
```